# Sympy substitute does not work with real variables

Tags: python, sympy

In Sympy, when a symbol is real (`real=True`), it is not substituted using `subs()`.
Even when `real` is `false`, it doesn't work.
Whenever `real` is specified in `symbols()` call, the substitution `subs()` does not work.
Otherwise, it works:

```py
import sympy

X = sympy.symbols("X")
print('i', X.subs(  {'X': 1.01}  )) # works

X = sympy.symbols("X", real=True) # `real=` Seems to be the cause of the problem
print('ii', X.subs(  {'X': 2.02}  ))

X = sympy.symbols("X", real=False) # even this
print('iii', X.subs(  {'X': 3.03}  ))
```

output:

```
i 1.01000000000000
ii X
iii X
```

For some reason, I need to specify the assumption `real=True`.

My `sympy.__version__` is : `1.10.1`

Comment: The subs does work on `(1*X).subs(  {'X': 2.0}  )`.

Comment: For me this didn't work too. Note: You need to define `X = sympy.symbols("X", real=True)`

Comment: Yes, I was testing various things and forgot that the latest `X` definition didn't have the assumption.  But with further trial I found that `X.subs(  {X: 2.0}  )` works - for the reason that David explained.

Comment: The `# causes problem` comment is ambiguous.  Did it raise an `error`, or just not work as you expected.  I had to do my own testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That behavior is to be expected: when you call `.subs({'X': 3.03})`, the `'X'` is going to be "simpified" ie, it is going to be converted to a generic new symbol (with no assumptions).

In your case:

```
X = sympy.symbols("X", real=False) # even this
print('iii', X.subs(  {'X': 3.03}  ))
# iii X
```

that's because `X` is a symbol with assumptions, and `'X'` will be converted to a symbol with no assumptions: they are different symbols, even though they share the name!

To understand it better, you can do something like this:

```
x1 = sympy.symbols("x")
x2 = sympy.symbols("x", real=True)
print(x1.equals(x2))
# out: False
print(x1 == x2)
# out: False
```

When you call `subs` you should be as specific as possible:

```
X = sympy.symbols("X", real=False) # even this
print('iii', X.subs(  {X: 3.03}  ))
# out: iii 3.03000000000000
```

Keep in mind that `subs` is meant to work on larger expressions, composed by one or multiple symbols.

Comment: Excellent, that fully answered my question.

Comment: So, even `sympy.symbols("X", real=False)` is a symbol with assumptions, despite `real` being `False`.